# function argument as case expression

Tags: java

The following function is supposed to calculate the i-th smallest element of a sorted list that it takes as argument.
I wanted to use a "*switch*" expression inside my function instead of "*if*".

The compiler gives me the following error : "*case expression must be constant expression*"

Please note that the function is obviously not complete.

```
public int search(int[] a, int i) {
    ArrayList <Integer> smaller_than = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
    ArrayList <Integer> greater_than = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
    int pivot = a[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (a[j] < pivot) {
            smaller_than.add(a[j]);
        }

        if (a[j] >= pivot) {
            greater_than.add(a[j]);
        }
    }

    switch (smaller_than.size()) {    
        case i:
            return greater_than.get(1); <----    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know how can I satisfy the case expression requirement, knowing that a parameter taken as argument has to be declared as constant.

Comment: The compilation error is pretty self-explanatory. Use an `if` to compare `i == smaller_than.size()`

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) or bother to [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=case+expression+must+be+constant+expression)?

Comment: This use really is not what switch is intended for.

Comment: Ok, so really have to use an if, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that **you cannot do what you are trying to do**.

You cannot use a `switch` statement for this.

Use an `if` statement instead.

Comment: As blgt said, the compilation error is pretty self-explanatory. Basically, because the java language specification says so.

Comment: In depth explanation: every `case` in `switch` have their own address in memory. It cant be dynamic.

Comment: Thanks @talex - I think that says more that just "because Java says so" :-)

Comment: In-depth-in-depth-explanation [can be found in the JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10)

Comment: Actually, guys, there exist other languages where you can have whatever you want in the case labels, so it does really boil down to "because java says so".  But this is a philosophical issue.